# Delete files from a folder in Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, filesystems, delete-file

I have a controller with a `createAction` an `editAction` and a `deleteAction`.

I can add pictures and delete them from the database.

As I followed the Symfony doc to create an uploader file, I also created in my `config.yml` this route

```
parameters:
   uploaded_restaurants: "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/restaurants"
```

so this is the routes for my uploaded files.

**My problem**

When I delete my pictures with my delete action, its fine it deletes it in my database. But not in my folder `/web/uploads/restaurants`
I tried to find a way to be able to delete them in my folder too, but couldn't succeed it.

I tried also with a `Filesystem()` to remove them, but I've must have written it badly.

Here is my controller:

```
    class MediaController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Restaurant $restaurant
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request, Restaurant $restaurant)
    {
        $media = new Media();
        $form = $this->createForm(MediaType\CreateType::class, $media);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $mediaList = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Media')->findImageByRestaurantType($restaurant, $form->get('context')->getData());

            if ($mediaList == null || count($mediaList) < 1) {
                $media->setType('img')
                    ->setContext($form->get('context')->getData())
                    ;
            } else {
                $media = $mediaList;
            }

            $imageFile = $request->files->get('create')['name'];
            $targetDir = $this->getParameter('uploaded_restaurants');
            $imageName = $this->get('app.uploader')->upload($imageFile, $targetDir);

            /** @var  $originalName */
            $originalName = $imageFile->getClientOriginalName();
            $media->setName($imageName)
                ->setOriginalName($originalName)
                ->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $media->setRestaurant($restaurant);
            $em->persist($media);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_restaurant_show_fr', array('id' => $restaurant->getId()));
        }
        return $this->render('admin/restaurant/media/new.html.twig', array(
            'restaurant' => $restaurant,
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Media $media
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, Media $media)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $editForm = $this->createForm(MediaType\EditType::class, $media);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);
        $restaurant = $media->getRestaurant();

        if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
            $imageFile = $request->files->get('edit')['name'];
            $targetDir = $this->getParameter('uploaded_restaurants');
            $imageName = $this->get('app.uploader')->upload($imageFile, $targetDir);

            if ($request->files->get('edit')['name'] != null) {

                $fs = new Filesystem();
                try {
                    $fs->remove($this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web/uploads/restaurants' . $media->getName());
                } catch (IOException $e) {
                    echo "error";
                }

                /** @var $originalName */
                $originalName = $imageFile->getClientOriginalName();
                $media->setName($imageName)
                    ->setOriginalName($originalName)
                    ->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());
            }
            $em->persist($media);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_restaurant_show_fr', array('id' => $restaurant->getId()));
        }
        return $this->render('admin/restaurant/media/edit.html.twig', array(
            'media' => $media,
            'restaurant' => $restaurant,
            'editForm' => $editForm->createView()
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @param Media $media
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function deleteAction(Media $media)
    {
        $restaurant = $media->getRestaurant();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($media);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_restaurant_show_fr', array('id' => $restaurant->getId()));
    }
}
```

As you can see in the editAction I tried to add a `Filesystem` in order to remove the file

**my question**

How can I do that for my `editAction` and my `deleteAction` in order to delete properly my files from the directory?
If you don't really understand my code, is there an example you can show me that works?
Thank you

Comment: Have you thought about using [VichUploaderBundle](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle) (which is even suggested in the official docu)? It already implement this

Comment: hi @kero, thanks for your comment. Actually in my project I can't use any bundle as my lead wants me to do it.... like that :/ so anyway thank you for your answer, I will consider vich on future project obviously :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both when editing or deleting a media you have the existing object with it's filename available, e.g.:

```
public function deleteAction(Media $media){ ... }
```

Doctrine will read the id from the url and load the corresponding media from database. You can use this object to get the old image location and then remove that image.

```
// getName() will contain the complete filename with path.
// Check your showAction where you call `setName($imageName)`
$filename = $media->getName();

$filesystem = new Filesystem();
$filesystem->remove($filename);
```

You can do the same in your editAction instead of the code you provided.

Comment: hi @dbrumann, thank you for your answer. Just your two line will do the trick? seriously that simple? I cannot test right now as im leaving office, but at home I would try.

Comment: I added this line using your logic `$fs = new Filesystem();
            $fs->remove($this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/../web/uploads/restaurants/'.$oldName);` and it worked :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

config/services.yaml

```
parameters:
      img_dir: "%kernel.project_dir%/public/img"
      public_dir: "%kernel.project_dir%/public"
```

controller edit

```
public function edit(Request $request, Layanan $layanan, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
{
// ....
    $file = $form->get('image')->getData();
    $fs = new Filesystem();
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        if ($file) {
            $fname = $layanan->getImage();
            $fs->remove($this->getParameter('public_dir').'/img/'.$fname);
            $newFilename = $originalfilename . '-' . uniqid() . '.' . $file->guessExtension();
            try {
                $file->move(
                    $this->getParameter('img_dir'),
                    $newFilename
                );
            } catch (FileException $e) {
                // ... handle exception if something happens during file upload
            }
            $layanan->setImage($newFilename);
        }
//...
}
```